# How to get an unmodified URL for an image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have a logo on my website that I want to use on other site as well. (I can't copy it there).

On main site it's specified as 
`<%= image_tag "logo_new_v1.jpg" %>`

After `assets:precompile` it's get changed to `logo_new_v1-319364c3d16b335b3c99827b797a21bf.jpg`

So the only way (which I found) to reference it from another site is using this URL:
http://www.domain.com/assets/logo_new_v1-319364c3d16b335b3c99827b797a21bf.jpg

But instead I would prefer to reference it by this one:
http://www.domain.com/assets/logo_new_v1.jpg

Is it possible?

Comment: What's the physical path of your file?

Comment: You can make assets folder readable for everyone, and it should work.

Comment: where/in which folder is your image stored?

Comment: APP_NAME/app/assets/images/logo_new_v1.jpg

Comment: Lawrence, how can I make it readable? I am on Heroku

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [non-stupid-digest-assets](https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets) gem to force the asset pipeline to keep the original image file.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's correct way to do it.
http://www.domain.com/assets/logo_new_v1.jpg

Comment: Sure it is. www.domain.com is just a placeholder.